# Flask web application (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-applications, flask, pydev

I'm working on a flask web application and I'm new in flask. My problem is that I want to do some things only once. For example to instantiate SearchClass and SC.refreshArray() which should be independent on refreshing my web page to increase a speed of application. Will you give me an advice how to manage that? This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template
from SearchClass import *
from Database import getConnection
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('my-form.html')

def fileSuffixArray():
    with open("saf.txt", 'rb') as f:
        my_list = pickle.load(f)
        print(my_list)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def search():
    text = request.form['text']

    db = getConnection("db")

    SC = SearchClass(db)
    SC.refreshArray()
    results=SC.getPhrase(text) 
    s=""
    for i in range(0,len(results)):
        resString=""
        res=Database.searchForExactTranslation(results[i], db)
        resString= ' '.join(res)
        s+="<b>%s: </b> %s<br>" % (results[i], resString)

    return s

app.debug = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your code to set up the database connection to a function and call the function before calling app.run()

```
SC = None
def setupdb():
  global SC
  db = getConnection("db")
  SC = SearchClass(db)
  SC.refreshArray()

if __name__== "__main__":
   setupdb()
   app.run()
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems correct, but now I'm getting this error. ProgrammingError: "SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 5224 and this is thread id 4652" I don't know what to do.